# Automatically generating sums in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is a design issue I came across while working on implementation of [Generalized Distributive Law](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.125.8954). Suppose you need to automatically generate expressions of the following form

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/sum-prod-formula.png))</sub>

Terms inside the sum, fixed variables and "summed over" variables are automatically generated for each such expression, and "f" functions are defined separately. To generate expression above, I may need to call

```
sumProduct(factors,fixedVariables,fixedValues,freeVariables,freeRanges)
```

where

```
factors={{1,4},{3,4},{3,4,5}}
fixedVariables={1,3}
fixedValues={-1,9}
freeVariables={4,5}
freeRanges={Range[5],Range[6]}
```

and the output of that function will be equivalent to

```
Total[{f14[-1,1]f34[9,1]f345[9,1,1],f14[-1,2]f34[9,2]f345[9,2,1],....}]
```

Representation of f terms could be different, ie f[{1,4},{-1,1}] instead of f14[-1,1]. Also using Integer to refer to each variable is just one design choice.

Can anyone suggest an elegant approach to implementing sumProduct?

**Edit 11/11**
Janus' solution, rewritten for readability

```
factors = {{1, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
vars = {{1, {-1}}, {3, {9}}, {4, Range[5]}, {5, Range[6]}};

(* list of numbers => list of vars *)
arglist[factor_] := Subscript[x, #] & /@ factor;

(* list of factors => list of functions for those factors *)
terms = Apply[f[#], arglist[#]] & /@ factors;

(* {var,range} pairs for each variable *)
args = {Subscript[x, #1], #2} & @@@ vars;

Sum[Times @@ terms, Sequence @@ args]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bunch together the fixed and free variables and specify them all in a list as

```
variables={{1,{-1}},{3,{9}},{4,Range[5]},{5,Range[6]}};
```

Then your `sumProduct` can be implemented quite concisely

```
sumProduct[f_, factors_, vars_] := Module[{x}, Sum[
   Times @@ ((Subscript[f, ##] @@ (Subscript[x, #] & /@ {##}) &) @@@ factors),
   Sequence @@ ({Subscript[x, #1], #2} & @@@ vars)]]
```

Which is called as `sumProduct[f,factors,variables]` to spit out a long thing:

```
Subscript[f, 1,4][-1,1] Subscript[f, 3,4][9,1] Subscript[f, 3,4,5][9,1,1]+....
```

Was this what you were after?

Comment: This works with symbols for variables as well, e.g. `sumProduct[f, {{a, b}}, {{a, {1, 2}}, {b, {0}}}]`.

Comment: +1 Specifying the fixed and free variables in this way makes thing easier.

Comment: @Yaroslaw Does your edit imply that my code is unreadable -- just because it contains such substrings as `, #] & /@ {##}) &) @@@ `? ;)  You just can't beat Mathematica for job security code.