# Define Custom Notation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often need to extract to restrict value lists to sublists, ie if `vals` gives values of `vars={x1,x2,x3,x4}`, and I need values of `svars={x2,x4}` I do `restrict[list,vars,svars]` where

```
restrict[vars_, svars_, vals_] := 
 Extract[vals, Flatten[Position[vars, #] & /@ svars, 1]]
```

I'd like to improve code readability, perhaps by defining following custom notation for `restrict[vars,svars,vals]`

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/custom-notation.png))</sub>

My questions are

1. What is a good way to implement this?
2. Is this a good idea altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good notations can be very useful - but I'm not sure that this particular one is needed...

That said, the `Notation` package makes this pretty easy. As there are many hidden boxes when you use the Notation palette, I'll use a screenshot: [image]

You can see the underlying `NotationMake*` downvalues construct by using the `Action -> PrintNotationRules` option. In[4] in the screenshot generates

```
NotationMakeExpression[
  SubscriptBox[vals_, RowBox[{vars_, "|", svars_}]], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[
  RowBox[{"restrict", "[", RowBox[{vars, ",", svars, ",", vals}], 
    "]"}], StandardForm]

NotationMakeBoxes[Subscript[vals_, vars_ | svars_], StandardForm] := 
 SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes[vals, StandardForm], 
  RowBox[{Parenthesize[vars, StandardForm, Alternatives], "|", 
    Parenthesize[svars, StandardForm, Alternatives]}]]
```

Comment: Related question, how do I get to Notation Palette? I found a link to it in one of the Tutorials, but it's not in my Palette's menu

Comment: Provided `Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette == True` it should open automatically when you `Need["Notation'"]`. If it doesn't then you can open it from `ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Packages", "Notation", "LocalPalettes", "English"}, ""]` and/or install it from the Palette menu.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to 2: I would pass the rule list `Thread[vars -> vals]` instead of keeping track of names and values separately.
One of my favorite Mathematica idioms is to use rule lists together with `WithRules` as defined below: This construct evaluates an expression in a `With` block where all the replacement symbols have been (recursively defined). This allow you to do stuff like

```
WithRules[{a -> 1, b -> 2 a + 1}, b]
```

and gets you quite far towards named arguments.

```
SetAttributes[WithRules, HoldRest]
WithRules[rules_, expr_] := Module[{notSet}, Quiet[
     With[{args = Reverse[rules /. Rule[a_, b_] -> notSet[a, b]]},
       Fold[With[{#2}, #1] &, expr, args]] /. notSet -> Set, 
   With::lvw]]
```

Edit: The `WithRules` construct is based on these two usenet threads (thanks to Simon for digging them up):

- [A version of With that binds variables sequentially](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/6fa6b0ad9d5d111c)
- [Add syntax highlighting to own command](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3a5ae92bda1c7511)

Comment: It's similar usage to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152194/automatically-generating-sums-in-mathematica/4152797#4152797 . IE, I sum f1(x1,x2)*f2(x2,x3) over x1,x2,x3 where fi's arguments are stored in args[fi]

Comment: OK, so this probably isn't so helpful then. Still, it is my favorite trick, so any excuse will do for posting it :)

Comment: It is a nice trick. I remember a similar method discussed in [this mathgroup post](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/6fa6b0ad9d5d111c).

Comment: Also [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3a5ae92bda1c7511) (which is the actual discussion that I remember!)

Comment: @Simon: Yes, exactly! Thanks for finding them (I gave it a quick try with no luck). Have added links to my answer for future reference.