# Using `With` with a list of `Rules` - but without affecting the normal behaviour of `With`

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Say I have a list of `Rules`

```
rules = {a -> b, c -> d};
```

which I use throughout a notebook. Then, at one point, it makes sense to want the rules to apply **before any other evaluations take place in an expression**. Normally if you want something like this you would use

```
In[2]:= With[{a=b,c=d}, expr[a,b,c,d]]
Out[2]= expr[b, b, d, d]
```

How can I take `rules` and insert it into the first argument of `With`?

---

### Edit

<strike>Both</strike>Some solutions fail do all that I was looking for - but I should have emphasised this point a little more. See the bold part above.

For example, let's look at

```
rules = {a -> {1, 2}, c -> 1};
```

If I use these vaules in `With`, I get

```
In[10]:= With[{a={1,2},c=1}, Head/@{a,c}]
Out[10]= {List,Integer}
```

Some versions of `WithRules` yield

```
In[11]:= WithRules[rules, Head/@{a,c}]
Out[11]= {Symbol, Symbol}
```

(**Actually**, I didn't notice that Andrew's answer had the Attribute `HoldRest` - so it works just like I wanted.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use [Hold](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) to build up your With statement. Here is one way; there may be a simpler:

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[WithRules, HoldRest]

In[2]:= WithRules[rules_, expr_] := 
 With @@ Append[Apply[Set, Hold@rules, {2}], Unevaluated[expr]]
```

Test it out:

```
In[3]:= f[args___] := Print[{args}]

In[4]:= rules = {a -> b, c -> d};

In[5]:= WithRules[rules, f[a, c]]

During evaluation of In[5]:= {b,d}
```

(I used Print so that any bug involving me accidentally evaluating expr too early would be made obvious.)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the following form of  `WithRules` for a long time. Compared to the one posted by Andrew Moylan, it binds sequentially so that you can say e.g. `WithRules[{a->b+1, b->2},expr]` and get `a` expanded to `3`:

```
SetAttributes[WithRules, HoldRest]
WithRules[rules_, expr_] := ReleaseHold@Module[{notSet}, Quiet[
     With[{args = Reverse[rules /. Rule[a_, b_] -> notSet[a, b]]},
       Fold[With[{#2}, #1] &, Hold@expr, args]] /. notSet -> Set, 
   With::lvw]]
```

This was also posted as an [answer to an unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190845/custom-notation-question/4191096#4191096), and as noted there, it has been discussed (at least) a couple of times on usenet:

- [A version of With that binds variables sequentially](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/6fa6b0ad9d5d111c)
- [Add syntax highlighting to own command](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3a5ae92bda1c7511)

HTH

**EDIT**: Added a `ReleaseHold`, `Hold` pair to keep `expr` unevaluated until the rules have been applied.

Comment: Thanks Janus! Now that you mention it, I remember at least one of those "sequential `With`" [discussions in mathgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/OlrpK9ocdRE). Your answer doesn't quite behave the way that I wanted - see the edits.

Comment: @Simon, fixed it to actually be an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One problem with Andrew's solution is that it maps the problem back to With, and that does not accept subscripted variables. So the following generates messages.

```
WithRules[{Subscript[x, 1] -> 2, Subscript[x, 2] -> 3}, 
 Power[Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]]]
```

Given that `With` performs syntactic replacement on its body, we can set WithRules alternatively as follows:

```
ClearAll[WithRules]; SetAttributes[WithRules, HoldRest];
WithRules[r : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..}, body_] := 
 ReleaseHold[Hold[body] /. r]
```

Then

```
In[113]:= WithRules[{Subscript[x, 1] -> 2, 
  Subscript[x, 2] -> 3}, Subscript[x, 1]^Subscript[x, 2]]

Out[113]= 8
```

**Edit**: Addressing valid concerns raised by Leonid, the following version would be safe:

```
ClearAll[WithRules3]; SetAttributes[WithRules3, HoldRest];
WithRules3[r : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..}, body_] := 
 Developer`ReplaceAllUnheld[Unevaluated[body], r]
```

Then

```
In[194]:= WithRules3[{Subscript[x, 1] -> 2, Subscript[x, 2] -> 3}, 
 Subscript[x, 1]^Subscript[x, 2]]

Out[194]= 8

In[195]:= WithRules3[{x -> y}, f[y_] :> Function[x, x + y]]

Out[195]= f[y_] :> Function[x, x + y]
```

**Edit 2**: Even WithRules3 is not completely equivalent to Andrew's version:

```
In[206]:= WithRules3[{z -> 2}, f[y_] :> Function[x, x + y + z]]

Out[206]= f[y_] :> Function[x, x + y + z]

In[207]:= WithRules[{z -> 2}, f[y_] :> Function[x, x + y + z]]

Out[207]= f[y$_] :> Function[x$, x$ + y$ + 2]
```

Comment: If that is all that is required, cannot one merely do `Unevaluated[Subscript[x, 1]^Subscript[x, 2]] /. {Subscript[x, 1] -> 2,
   Subscript[x, 2] -> 3}` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that is an alternative.

Comment: There are subtle differences in semantics of With and rule-based substitutions, that will show up when the code in "body" has nested scoping constructs with local variable names colliding with some of the symbols in rules. Using With will favor inner constructs, using rules will favor outer rules and break the inner scoping constructs bindings. What is advantageous, depends on the code in question, but my feeling is that the "With" way is generally safer.

Comment: Nice one. Having a version of With that handles non-symbols, such as subscripted variables, is a really handy generalization.

Comment: @Andrew  As I already commented, this is not really a version of  `With`, but rather a utility automating external rule application to an unevaluated expression. Try, for example, `WithRules[{x -> y}, f[y_] :> Function[x, x + y]]` with both yours and @Sasha's solutions, to see the difference. In the context of lexical scoping, I consider rule substitution far more dangerous. It is, in particular, responsible for the leaks in the functional abstraction (`Function`) in Mathematica, one of which the above code snippet demonstrates.