# Using Context as a scoping construct in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, scoping

Thinking about a solution to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5663199/181759) about switching between numerical and analytical "modes" in a large Mathematica project, I thought about the idea of using `Context` as a scoping construct.

The basic idea is to make all numerical value assignments in their own context, e.g.

```
Begin["Global`Numerical`"]
par1 = 1;
par2 = 2;
...
End[]
```

and have all the complicated analytical functions, matrices, etc. in the Global context.

Ideally I would be able to work in the Global context and switch to everything being numeric with a simple `Begin[Global'Numeric']` and switch back with `End[]`.

Unfortunately this doen not work, since e.g. `f[par1_,par2_,...] := foo` defined in the Global context will not use `par1`, `par2`, etc which have been defined in a sub context of Global.

Is there a way to make sub contexts inherit definitions from their parent context? Is there some other way to use contexts to create a simple switchable scope?

Comment: You can always control scope by manually tweaking `$ContextPath`, but it's a fragile hack.  Personally, I haven't figured out a good way to use contexts for scoping, but I'm eager to see if others can suggest ideas.

Comment: Manually editing the `$ContextPath` isn't necessarily fragile, but you have to tread carefully. A good practice is to remember what it was before you modify it, and then set it back to the remembered value when you're leaving the "scope". You have to be careful to manage `Abort`s and other evaluation interruptions, too. @Leo, You should post the answer since you brought it up first. =)

Comment: Using `Block` as `Block[{$ContextPath = newValue}, your code]` will automatically take care of many dangers mentioned by @Michael (no need to explicitly remember the old value, no need to worry about exceptions and Abort-s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's one way to get around (what I think) is your problem by adjusting  `$ContextPath` appropriately:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> "GlobalTestCtxt`"];
Remove[f, GlobalTestCtxt`Numerical`f, par1, par2];
f[par1_, par2_] := {par1, par2};

savedContextPath = $ContextPath;
Begin["GlobalTestCtxt`Numerical`"];
Print[{$ContextPath, $Context}];
$ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "GlobalTestCtxt`"];
par1 = 1;
par2 = 2;
End[];
$ContextPath = savedContextPath;
```

Now, this will evaluate analytically:

```
f[par1, par2]
```

And this numerically:

```
savedContextPath = $ContextPath;
Begin["GlobalTestCtxt`Numerical`"];
$ContextPath = Prepend[$ContextPath, $Context];
f[par1, par2]
End[];
$ContextPath = savedContextPath;
```

The reason I say it's fragile is that unless you are careful, it's easy to get the symbol into the wrong context.  For instance, suppose you forgot to evaluate f in the global context before evaluating the "numerical" block.  Well, now your numerical block will not work simply because it'll turn to a (perfectly valid) symbol `` GlobalTestCtxt`Numerical`f ``, which you have inadvertently entered into the symbol table when you first evaluated the numerical block.  Because of potential bugs like this, I personally don't use this approach.

**Edit:** fixed a bug (it is necessary to hide the "Global" context when doing assignments in numerical context)

Comment: +1 Leo, I hope you don't mind that I changed your `x=PrependTo[x,y]`s to `x=Prepend[x,y]`. Although, you could just use `PrependTo[x,y]` if you want.