# Unevaluated form of a[[i]]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, operator-precedence

Consider following simple, illustrating example

```
cf = Block[{a, x, degree = 3},
  With[{expr = Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]},
   Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]
   ]
  ]
```

This is one of the possible ways to *transfer* code in the body of a Compile statement. It produces the Part::partd error, since a[[i]] is at the moment of evaluation not a list.

The easy solution is to just ignore this message or turn it off. There are of course other ways around it. For instance one could circumvent the evaluation of a[[i]] by replacing it inside the Compile-body *before* it is compiled

```
cf = ReleaseHold[Block[{a, x, degree = 3},
   With[{expr = Product[x - a[i], {i, degree}]},
    Hold[Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]] /. 
     a[i_] :> a[[i]]]
   ]
  ]
```

If the compiled function a large bit of code, the Hold, Release and the replacement at the end goes a bit against my idea of beautiful code. Is there a short and nice solution I have not considered yet?

### Answer to the post of Szabolcs

> Could you tell me though why you are using With here?

Yes, and it has to do with the reason why I cannot use := here. I use With, to have something like a `#define` in C, which means a code-replacement at the place I need it. Using := in With delays the evaluation and what the body of Compile sees is not the *final piece of code* which it is supposed to compile. Therefore,

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
cf = Block[{a, x, degree = 3}, 
   With[{expr := Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]}, 
    Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]]];
CompilePrint[cf]
```

shows you, that there is a call to the Mathematica-kernel in the compiled function

```
I4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x, a}, degree][ R0, T(R1)0]]
```

This is bad because Compile should use only the local variables to calculate the result.

## Update

Szabolcs solution works in this case but it leaves the whole expression unevaluated. Let me explain, why it is important that the expression is expanded before it is compiled. I have to admit, my toy-example was not the best. So lets try a better one using With and SetDelayed like in the solution of Szabolcs

```
Block[{a, x}, With[
  {expr := D[Product[x - a[[i]], {i, 3}], x]}, 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]
  ]
 ]
```

Say I have a polynomial of degree 3 and I need the derivative of it inside the Compile. In the above code I want Mathematica to calculate the derivative for unassigned roots a[[i]] so I can use the formula *very* often in the compiled code. Looking at the compiled code above
one sees, that the D[..] cannot be compiled as nicely as the Product and stays unevaluated

```
11  R1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[D][ R5, R0]]
```

Therefore, my updated question is: Is it possible to evaluate a piece of code without evaluating the Part[]-accesses in it better/nicer than using

```
Block[{a, x}, With[
  {expr = D[Quiet@Product[x - a[[i]], {i, 3}], x]}, 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]
  ]
 ]
```

*Edit: I put the Quiet to the place it belongs. I had it in front of code block to make it visible to everyone that I used Quiet here to suppress the warning. As Ruebenko pointed already out, it should in real code always be as close as possible to where it belongs. With this approach you probably don't miss other important warnings/errors.*

## Update 2

Since we're moving away from the original question, we should move this discussion maybe to a new thread. I don't know to whom I should give the best answer-award to my question since we discussed *Mathematica and Scoping* more than how to suppress the a[[i]] issue.

## Update 3

To give the final solution: I simply suppress (unfortunately like I did all the time) the a[[i]] warning with Quiet. In a real example below, I have to use Quiet outside the complete Block to suppress the warning.

To inject the required code into the body of Compile I use a pure function and give the code to inline as argument. This is the same approach Michael Trott is using in, e.g. his Numerics book. This is a bit like the `where` clause in Haskell, where you define stuff you used afterwards.

```
newtonC = Function[{degree, f, df, colors},
   Compile[{{x0, _Complex, 0}, {a, _Complex, 1}},
    Block[{x = x0, xn = 0.0 + 0.0 I, i = 0, maxiter = 256, 
      eps = 10^(-6.), zeroId = 1, j = 1},
     For[i = 0, i < maxiter, ++i,
      xn = x - f/(df + eps);
      If[Abs[xn - x] < eps,
       Break[]
       ];
      x = xn;
      ];
     For[j = 1, j <= degree, ++j,
      If[Abs[xn - a[[j]]] < eps*10^2,
        zeroId = j + 1;
        Break[];
        ];
      ];
     colors[[zeroId]]*(1 - (i/maxiter)^0.3)*1.5
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True]]@@
    (Quiet@Block[{degree = 3, polynomial, a, x},
     polynomial = HornerForm[Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]];
     {degree, polynomial, HornerForm[D[polynomial, x]], 
      List @@@ (ColorData[52, #] & /@ Range[degree + 1])}])
```

And this function is now fast enough to calculate the Newton-fractal of a polynomial where the position of the roots is not fixed. Therefore, we can adjust the roots dynamically.
Feel free to adjust n. Here it runs up to n=756 fluently

```
(* ImageSize n*n, Complex plange from -b-I*b to b+I*b *)
With[{n = 256, b = 2.0},
 DynamicModule[{
   roots = RandomReal[{-b, b}, {3, 2}],
   raster = Table[x + I y, {y, -b, b, 2 b/n}, {x, -b, b, 2 b/n}]},
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[roots],
   Dynamic[
    Graphics[{Inset[
       Image[Reverse@newtonC[raster, Complex @@@ roots], "Real"],
       {-b, -b}, {1, 1}, 2 {b, b}]}, PlotRange -> {{-b, b}, {-
         b, b}}, ImageSize -> {n, n}]], {{-b, -b}, {b, b}}, 
   Appearance -> Style["\[Times]", Red, 20]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Teaser:

[image: Dynamic Newton fractal]

Comment: Now we have something completely different.  Now you are evaluating the `Product` outside the `Compile` so you can differentiate it, leaving nothing to do for `Compile` (in this simple example, of course).  Anyway, it looks like to me: 1. first you want to generate code 2. then you want to compile it.  In this example you use the result of `D` to generate code.  Let me think for a while.

Comment: But please do check that in your real code there *is* something left for `Compile` to do, and it's not merely a plain formula that you pass to it.  (In you first example it uses a specialized version of `Product` so it does do something ...)

Comment: I was wrong here, `Compile` does speed up simple expressions too, as verified on a long series expansion after turning off auto-compilation by `Map`.  Though vectorization may give better results (if all functions in the expression are `Listable`, as is the case in a series expansion).

Comment: I'd put the quite as close to the function you want to quiet as you can, Quiet is evil! You will miss real bugs due to it; try to minimize it's effect.

Comment: I don't have more time to spend on this today, but I want to point out a caveat with localization!  **Big warning** The fact that `With[{y = x}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, y]]` works they way you intend might be an accident.  Consider `With[{y = x}, Compile[x, y]]`, outputting `CompiledFunction[{x$},x,-CompiledCode-]` where `x` gets localized in `Compile`.

Comment: @Szabolcs It is always the outer scoping construct that performs localization and renamings - otherwise this would contradict the general evaluation semantics, since all scoping constructs are `HoldAll` and the inner ones simply have no chance to do anything before the outer ones. In your example, it was `With`, and to fool it, you need e.g. this: `With[{y = x}, Compile @@ Hold[x, y]]`. I described it more fully here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808

Comment: @Leonid Today I really feel that these complexities hurt usability too much.  Why can't it have a scoping system that I can learn in one afternoon and not get confused by it even after years of use?

Comment: @Szabolcs I think the real problem is that the M scoping system is really an *emulation* of lexical scoping as it exists in more traditional languages. In a sense, M is over-transparent - you can do pretty sophisticated scope surgery since all scoping constructs are expressions and are exposed to you. So, in a way, I think this could not be avoided, if one wants to remain true to the core design principles of M. OTOH, scoping is not *that* complicated - most of the non-trivial stuff can be deduced from e.g. the discussion I linked to. I think it just has not been described in an ...

Comment: @Szabolcs ...understandable way in existing literature (which, I think, applies to many of the M core features. This is one of the main reasons for my work on another M book). In my experience, scoping did not give me any trouble for quite a long time already, once I understoof it, and I'd argue that at the core, it is rather simple. Finally, let's be fair - in more traditional languages, things are simpler, but our ambitions are much lower too - they simply don't provide means to forge new scoping constructs. A good way to grok scoping is to make your own scoping construct emulations.

Comment: @Leonid What I mean is that I'm frustrated by behaviour like that of `Compile`. Did you anticipate this issue with the OPs example?  (I.e. that if he used `Compile[{x}, ...]` instead of `Compile[{{x, _Real}}, ...]` then it would not be possible to inject the code with either `With` or `Function` without having the variable `x` renamed?  It is of course true that code generation is not really easy, and problems with evaluation/localization are to be expected.  Such things don't often come up, so we don't run into these problems day to day.

Comment: @Szabolcs Let me put it this way: I would not be able to predict that that would happen for sure, but I am not surprised at all, and I'd definitely make a check when trying this, anticipating something like this. `Compile` is not as well integrated into the overall scoping scheme as other things, and you can get some compilation bugs when defining global values for variables used afterwards inside `Compile`. From the M scoping perspective, the behavior that allows to inject all right into `Compile[{{x, _Real}}, ...]` *is* a bug, while the observed behavior with  `Compile[{x}, ...]` is correct.

Comment: @Szabolcs While we are at the topic of injecting into scoping costructs - a radical method which would always work is to use replacement rules (or parameter-passing in (pure or pattern-defined) functions, which has similar semantics. I actually used both in the answer which I now deleted). I know that `With` is a recommended way to inject into unevaluated code, and it is probably right since it is safer, but for scope surgery, rules are the way to go (they are quite ruthless and don't care about the scoping of the code where they do replacements).

Comment: @Leonid You should undelete your answer, I think.  Even if the `With[{expr := ... } ...]` answer seemed more appropriate to the original question, it's always good to see more ways.  And the situation has changes since then.

Comment: @Szabolcs I decided to add another answer instead, where I posted a *very* oversimplified version of the real code-generating framework I ended up with (after first using a version of what I described in my answer for M code generation and what you described here under the name of macro-expansion). The full framework is hugely more powerful than local rule application, since it allows one to fully leverage the M evaluator during the code expansion, including things like attributes and  recursive evaluation strategy.

Comment: As an active member of the Mathematica tag, have you considered committing to the [area51.se] [Mathematica proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=DamSFi3dv5QIDM_9uBjtlA2)? We could use your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
cf = Block[{a, x, degree = 3}, 
  With[{expr = Quiet[Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]]}, 
   Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]]]
```

be careful though, it you really want this.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant by *ignore this message or turn it off.*

Comment: Here is another way, without Quiet. Undocumented, and actually for a different purpose: cf = Block[{a, x, degree = 3}, 
  With[{expr = 
     D[Product[x - Compile`GetElement[a, i], {i, degree}], x]}, 
   Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]]]; Compile`GetElement will not check bounds, very careful with this one.

Comment: @ruebenko We have a proposal for a [mathematica specific site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=hWeRiD9Qz0oIDM_9uBjtlA2) for anything related to mathematica. It would be nice if you could commit (involves creating an Area51 account) to the proposal. We're pretty close to launching (only need about 50 more users). My apologies if you have already done so.

Comment: @yoda, Leonid told me, but I just have not had the time to look at it yet.

Comment: @ruebenko, very nice. Who needs boundary checks? They only take valuable cpu-time;-) Thanks.

Comment: @halirutan, you will crash if out of bounds, but it is useful to know. It's a bit of a pity that part gives a message for symbols. Have you tried compared the timings for Part and GetElement? What else do you need for a best answer?

Comment: @ruebenko, yes, I did the timings: Although I access only the 3-10 roots of the polynomial, there is a speedup with GetElement.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, here is the *very* oversimplified version of the code generation framework I am using for various purposes:

```
ClearAll[symbolToHideQ]
SetAttributes[symbolToHideQ, HoldFirst];
symbolToHideQ[s_Symbol, expandedSymbs_] :=! MemberQ[expandedSymbs, Unevaluated[s]];

ClearAll[globalProperties]
globalProperties[] := {DownValues, SubValues, UpValues (*,OwnValues*)};

ClearAll[getSymbolsToHide];
Options[getSymbolsToHide] = {
     Exceptions -> {List, Hold, HoldComplete, 
        HoldForm, HoldPattern, Blank, BlankSequence, BlankNullSequence, 
       Optional, Repeated, Verbatim, Pattern, RuleDelayed, Rule, True, 
       False, Integer, Real, Complex, Alternatives, String, 
       PatternTest,(*Note-  this one is dangerous since it opens a hole 
                    to evaluation leaks. But too good to be ingored *)
       Condition, PatternSequence, Except
      }
 };

getSymbolsToHide[code_Hold, headsToExpand : {___Symbol}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Join @@ Complement[
       Cases[{
          Flatten[Outer[Compose, globalProperties[], headsToExpand]], code},
            s_Symbol /; symbolToHideQ[s, headsToExpand] :> Hold[s],
            Infinity,
            Heads -> True
       ],
       Hold /@ OptionValue[Exceptions]];

ClearAll[makeHidingSymbol]
SetAttributes[makeHidingSymbol, HoldAll];
makeHidingSymbol[s_Symbol] := 
    Unique[hidingSymbol(*Unevaluated[s]*) (*,Attributes[s]*)];

ClearAll[makeHidingRules]
makeHidingRules[symbs : Hold[__Symbol]] :=
     Thread[List @@ Map[HoldPattern, symbs] -> List @@ Map[makeHidingSymbol, symbs]];

ClearAll[reverseHidingRules];
reverseHidingRules[rules : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..}] :=
   rules /. (Rule | RuleDelayed)[Verbatim[HoldPattern][lhs_], rhs_] :> (rhs :> lhs);


FrozenCodeEval[code_Hold, headsToEvaluate : {___Symbol}] :=   
   Module[{symbolsToHide, hidingRules, revHidingRules,  result}, 
      symbolsToHide = getSymbolsToHide[code, headsToEvaluate];
      hidingRules = makeHidingRules[symbolsToHide];
      revHidingRules = reverseHidingRules[hidingRules];
      result = 
         Hold[Evaluate[ReleaseHold[code /. hidingRules]]] /. revHidingRules;
      Apply[Remove, revHidingRules[[All, 1]]];
      result];
```

The code works by temporarily hiding most symbols with some dummy ones, and allow certain symbols evaluate. Here is how this would work here:

```
In[80]:= 
FrozenCodeEval[
  Hold[Compile[{{x,_Real,0},{a,_Real,1}},D[Product[x-a[[i]],{i,3}],x]]],
  {D,Product,Derivative,Plus}
]

Out[80]= 
Hold[Compile[{{x,_Real,0},{a,_Real,1}},
  (x-a[[1]]) (x-a[[2]])+(x-a[[1]]) (x-a[[3]])+(x-a[[2]]) (x-a[[3]])]]
```

So, to use it, you have to wrap your code in `Hold` and indicate which heads you want to evaluate. What remains here is just to apply `ReleseHold` to it. Note that the above code just illustrates the ideas, but is still quite limited. The full version of my method involves other steps which make it much more powerful but also more complex.

*Edit*

While the above code is still too limited to accomodate many really interesting cases, here is one additional neat example of what would be  [rather hard to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373526/error-generating-localized-variables-as-constants/) with the traditional tools of evaluation control:

```
In[102]:= 
FrozenCodeEval[
  Hold[f[x_, y_, z_] := 
    With[Thread[{a, b, c} = Map[Sqrt, {x, y, z}]], 
       a + b + c]], 
  {Thread, Map}]

Out[102]= 
Hold[
  f[x_, y_, z_] := 
    With[{a = Sqrt[x], b = Sqrt[y], c = Sqrt[z]}, a + b + c]]
```

Comment: I just added `globalProperties` which I left out when cannibalizing the original code.

Comment: @Szabolcs I hope to see it published one day too! :). Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: This is indeet nice, so +1, but it is of course rather complex.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for the upvote. The idea here is, it may be complex, but it is a framework (although tiny), meaning that the tool is rather general. If we were shown the internal implementation of things like `With`, I am pretty sure that would look complex too. What you requested requires significant deviations from the standard evaluation procedure, and making such things possible *in general* is a complex task (achieved here only for a special set of use cases) - thus complex code.

Comment: @halirutan To illustrate what I meant in the comment above, I just added another simple example of what can be easily done - while there was a heated discussion of the similar topic here on SO some time ago, where you also contributed an answer.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** -- **Big warning!!**  Injecting code using `With` or `Function` into `Compile` that uses some of `Compile`'s local variables is not reliable!  Consider the following:

```
In[63]:= With[{y=x},Compile[x,y]]
Out[63]= CompiledFunction[{x$},x,-CompiledCode-]

In[64]:= With[{y=x},Compile[{{x,_Real}},y]]
Out[64]= CompiledFunction[{x},x,-CompiledCode-]
```

Note the renaming of `x` to `x$` in the first case.  I recommend you read about localization [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html).  (Yes, this is confusing!)  We can guess about why this only happens in the first case and not the second, but my point is that this behaviour might not be intended (call it a bug, dark corner or undefined behaviour), so relying on it is fragile ...

`Replace`-based solutions, like my [`withRules` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617773/695132) do work though (this was not my intended use for that function, but it fits well here ...)

```
In[65]:= withRules[{y->x},Compile[x,y]]
Out[65]= CompiledFunction[{x},x,-CompiledCode-]
```

---

### Original answers

You can use `:=` in `With`, like so:

```
cf = Block[{a, x, degree = 3},
  With[{expr := Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]},
   Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr]
   ]
  ]
```

It will avoid evaluating `expr` and the error from `Part`.

Generally, `=` and `:=` work as expected in all of `With`, `Module` and `Block`.

---

Could you tell me though why you are using `With` here? (I'm sure you have a good reason, I just can't see it from this simplified example.)

---

**Additional answer**

Addressing @halirutan's concern about `degree` not being inlined during compilation

I see this as exactly the same situation as if we had a global variable defined that we use in `Compile`.  Take for example:

```
In[18]:= global=1
Out[18]= 1

In[19]:= cf2=Compile[{},1+global]
Out[19]= CompiledFunction[{},1+global,-CompiledCode-]

In[20]:= CompilePrint[cf2]
Out[20]= 
        No argument
        3 Integer registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = 1
        Result = I2

1   I1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{}, global][ ]]
2   I2 = I0 + I1
3   Return
```

This is a common issue.  The solution is to tell `Compile` to [inline globals](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompilationOptions.html), like so:

```
cf = Block[{a, x, degree = 3}, 
   With[{expr := Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]}, 
    Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 1}}, expr, 
     CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]]];

CompilePrint[cf]
```

You can check that now there's no callback to the main evaluator.

---

Alternatively you can inject the value of `degree` using an extra layer of `With` instead of `Block`.  This will make you wish for [something like this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/wa6McJrYxiA/SstBgRPWmXoJ) very much.

---

### Macro expansion in Mathematica

This is somewhat unrelated, but you mention in your post that you use `With` for macro expansion.  Here's my first (possibly buggy) go at implementing macro expansion in Mathematica.  This is not well tested, feel free to try to break it and post a comment.

```
Clear[defineMacro, macros, expandMacros]

macros = Hold[];

SetAttributes[defineMacro, HoldAllComplete]
defineMacro[name_Symbol, value_] := (AppendTo[macros, name]; name := value)

SetAttributes[expandMacros, HoldAllComplete]
expandMacros[expr_] := Unevaluated[expr] //. Join @@ (OwnValues /@ macros)
```

**Description:**

`macros` is a (held) list of all symbols to be expanded.
`defineMacro` will make a new macro.
`expandMacros` will expand macro definitions in an expression.

Beware: I didn't implement macro-redefinition, this will not work while expansion is on using `$Pre`.  Also beware of recursive macro definitions and infinite loops.

**Usage:**

Do macro expansion on all input by defining `$Pre`:

```
$Pre = expandMacros;
```

Define `a` to have the value 1:

```
defineMacro[a, 1]
```

Set a delayed definition for `b`:

```
b := a + 1
```

Note that the definition of `b` is not fully evaluated, but `a` is expanded.

```
?b

Global`b

b:=1+1
```

Turn off macro expansion (`$Pre` can be dangerous if there's a bug in my code):

```
$Pre =.
```

Comment: +1 for `:=` - I had no idea that `With` can accept the delayed assignment syntax.

Comment: @Leonid That's why I included both `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` in [`withRules`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8617773/695132) :-)  Mathematica is just too huge a language, isn't it?  No matter how long I've been using it, there's always something seemingly simple that comes up that I didn't know about.  Last time it was the `TableHeadings` option of `MatrixForm`, which I have painfully reimplemented in the past using `Grid` (painfully because it drew my mind away from the main task at that time and because not being able to see the vertex ordering in my adjacency matrices was always annoying)

Comment: @halirutan I edited my answer to address this.  This is a different issue.  The solution is to tell the compiler to inline the definition.

Comment: @Szabolcs, sorry, I gave the wrong reason why := is unfortunately not the solution. I have to examine more carefully. I updated my post.

Comment: Your macro-expansion translates the problem because I have to use the evaluated form of my expression with defineMacro.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I agree - and M is so huge that one has to learn to strike a right balance between writing idiomatic mma and getting the job done. I am using M a lot, and I still often get trapped into some problem which takes hours and is basically using M to research M :). Regarding your macro-expansion: have a look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214946/how-to-dynamically-generate-mathematica-code/6215394#6215394, where I describe exactly the same method in detail. In general, you need `Hold[code]//.rules` though, and even this code-generating method is very limited.

Comment: @halirutan You can combine Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation with the macro-expansion to inject some evaluated pieces inside held expression, but, as I mentioned in the comment above, this macro-expansion method is still very limited. I use it in simple cases, but in more demanding ones I use a more complex technique based on `Block`-trick. I hope I will have time soon to publish a version of it as a package.

Answer (score 0):

Original code:

```
newtonC = Function[{degree, f, df, colors},
Compile[{{x0, _Complex, 0}, {a, _Complex, 1}},
Block[{x = x0, xn = 0.0 + 0.0 I, i = 0, maxiter = 256, 
...
RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True]]@@
(Quiet@Block[{degree = 3, polynomial, a, x},
 polynomial = HornerForm[Product[x - a[[i]], {i, degree}]];
...
```

Modified code:

```
newtonC = Function[{degree, f, df, colors},
Compile[{{x0, _Complex, 0}, {a, _Complex, 1}},
Block[{x = x0, xn = 0.0 + 0.0 I, i = 0, maxiter = 256, 
...
RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True],HoldAllComplete]@@
( (( (HoldComplete@@#)/.a[i_]:>a[[i]] )&)@Block[{degree = 3, polynomial, a, x},
 polynomial = HornerForm[Product[x - a[i], {i, degree}]];
...
```

Add `HoldAllComplete` attribute to the function.

Write `a[i]` in place of `a[[i]]`.

Replace `Quiet` with `(( (HoldComplete@@#)/.a[i_]:>a[[i]] )&)`

Produces the identical code, no `Quiet`, and all of the `Hold` stuff is in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to turn off this message-warning. After that you can turn it on

```
PartWarning[x_ : False] := 
  If[x === False, Print["Part warning is OFF"]; Off[Part::partd], 
   On[Part::partd]; Print["Part warning is ON"];];
```